# PHP Library for implementing transaction aware api calls?

Tags: php, transactions, rollback, enterprise

To implement a few of my functionalities, I need to call a set of APIs in order. There are times when one of the APIs in the middle fail. At such times I need to rollback the API calls that have successfully happened before that. Essentially a command / function queue with transaction rollback support.

Also there are times when I need to inject the result of one of the function calls as a parameter to a later function call. So it would be nice if there were a protocol for that.

What I would like to know if anyone has come across such a (php) library or if there is an elegant way to implement this, a State Machine maybe? Or am I talking just gibberish!!

Obviously, there are quite a few nuances to be considered, like what happens if the rollback too fails, etc..

I would like to call this library as below:

```php
    // First Command
    $cmd1 = 
        new \Transaction\Command("Command One")
            ->setFunction(
                function () {
                    echo "Running Command One";
                    return "One";
                }
            )
            ->setRollback(
                function () {
                    return "Rolled Back Command One";
                }
            );

    // Second Command
    $cmd2 = 
        new \Transaction\Command("Command Two")
            ->setFunction(
                function ($resultFromCmdOne) {
                    echo "Running Command Two with".
                        " result from command one: $resultFromCmdOne";
                    return "Two";
                }
            )
            ->setRollback(
                function () {
                    return "Rolled Back Command Two";
                }
            );

    $cmdQueue = new \Native5\Transaction\CommandQueue();
    $cmdQueue->addCommand($cmd1);
    $cmdQueue->addCommand($cmd2);

    // Process the set of commands 
    $cmdQueue->process();
```

Comment: Looks pretty decent to me. What is your problem? A standard library for such a problem does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the endorsement. I can implement a simple library on the lines of the presented code. But, given the problem is this the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't try to be too much of a perfectionist, you are on a good way here, so keep going on and improve the bottlenecks when you encounter them. Applications and requirements to them evolve over time, do your optimisation at the time, not beforehand.

Comment: Thanks will give a try at writing a small library around this.